# Differences between Amazon Kindle3 and iPod Touch Kindle app?

Tags: ipod-touch, ebook

I don't know exactly how long I can read books on Amazon Kindle3.
But I can read books on it for very long time without charging.

How long can I read books on iPod Touch Kindle app without charging?

Does Kindle for iPod Touch have the english dictionary function like Amazon Kindle?

Does Kindle for iPod Touch also support audible?

Which device is easier to use and read?

Are there other differences between Amazon Kindle3 and iPod Touch with Kindle?

Comment: ummm they are two completely different devices. No comparison at all. http://www.blogkindle.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/03/kindle-and-iphone.jpg

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
How long can I read books on iTouch Kindle without charging?
```

This will depend on the generation of the iPod touch you have. Newer generations have better battery life. This should be slightly more (+2 to +4 hours) than the video playback battery life of the device listed below:

- 1st generation: 5 hrs
- 2nd generation: 6 hrs
- 3rd generation: 6 hrs
- 4th generation: 7 hrs

It is modest in comparison to the battery life the kindle has.

```
Does iTouch Kindle have the english dictionary function like Amazon Kindle?
```

Yes it does. When you need to look up a word, select it and long press. The first time, the dictionary will download over a wi-fi connection. The second time on, it will look up the word without the need of an internet connection. Personnally, I've found the dictionary to not be very extensive.

```
Does iTouch Kindle also support audible?
```

Not sure what you're asking for here. I've never used a feature that has read out the content to me from the Kindle iPod touch and haven't seen an option for it either.

```
Which device is easier to use and read?
```

Definitely the Kindle device, since you're comparing which is better to read with.

```
Are there other differences between Amazon Kindle3 and iTouch Kindle?
```

- Supported formats: The iPod touch Kindle 2.7 doesn't support common formats like epub and pdf.
- Readability: The Kindle is larger and more suitable for reading. It's E Ink Pearl technology which displays everything in gray-scale, reduces glare and doesn't strain the eyes during long uses.
- Additional functions: The iPod touch can do much more that be a e-book reader. The number of apps available on the app store extends it capability. You also have the option to replace the Kindle on the iPod touch with other e-book reader apps like iBooks.

Comment: Thank you very much for your good and helpful answer!
Audible is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audible.com . I heard that Amazon Kindle started to support it recently. But I haven't used it yet.
I agree it's very important that the device `doesn't strain the eyes during long uses`. But iTouch is smaller and more portable and I can use iTouch easily even during brushing teeth, eating lunch, or walking. So if possible I wanna replace Amazon Kindle with iTouch Kindle.

Comment: Cool. But I'm recommending the iBooks app as well (for pdf and epub formats). Try it.